# setMaxResults and setFirstResult in Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

The [official Doctrine2 guide](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only) reports that:

"If your query contains a fetch-joined collection specifying the result limit methods are not working as you would expect. Set Max Results restricts the number of database result rows, however in the case of fetch-joined collections one root entity might appear in many rows, effectively hydrating less than the specified number of results."

It is my case. So what one can do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Doctrine2's built-in [Paginator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) and set `$fetchJoinCollection = true`.

Comment: This was not available in that time! It has been released since Doctrine 2.2.